# Recognize first loop run in XSLT

Tags: xslt, functional-programming, foreach

I am pretty new to XSLT and might be looking at my problem from the wrong angle - coming from languages such as C++ and Java. I hope someone can help me out.

I want to make a loop call (xsl:for-each) in XSLT and do something specific on the first run through the loop. In other languages I would use a status variable for this, but variables cannot change their value in XSLT as I have learned, so how can I solve this problem? Here is what I want to do. The upper case part in the if clause is of course fake and represents my problem.

```
<xsl:for-each select="browser/value">
 <xsl:if test="FIRST TIME IN LOOP">
  do something once
 </xsl:if>

 <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Thanks alot!
Henrik

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to check the position of the current node. It's also faster than checking the existence of preceding *value* elements in the tree (and will still work if `xsl:sort` is added to the loop):

```
<xsl:for-each select="browser/value">
  <xsl:if test="position()=1">
    do something here
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="blah"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to avoid thinking of "time". There is no first time, because XSLT execution is not ordered in time. But there is a first item in the input sequence, and you can tell when you are processing the first item in the sequence by testing position()=1.

Answer (score 2):

That is now how you do it - you need to stop thinking as a procedure, and start thinking more recursively.

(modified)

```
  <xsl:for-each select="browser/value">
      <xsl:if test="not(preceding::value[parent::browser])">
                first post!
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="blah"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

ie, if it is the first, there will be nothing before it. However, there may be other ways to do it outside of the loop

Comment: There are other ways, depending on the context, such as making node sets and itterating through them, working out the count of where you are etc. The key is to not think of the loop in the same way as a procedural language